# Custom python error class is always raising error

Tags: python, exception

I hope you can help me with some doubts about exception classes in python.
I don't want to use Exception class in my try/except statements so I have created a custom class:

```py
class MyCustomError (Exception): 
   pass
```

In my code, I want to control the exception so I use try/except sentence:

```py
def my_function():
  try:
    my code.....
  except MyCustomError as e:
    print("There is an error in my_function()")
```

If I use `MyCustomError`  to control the exception, it is raised. But if I use generic class `Exception`, exception is not raised and only print message is given.

How can I control the exceptions using a custom class as it is done using Exception class?

#### UPDATE

The code I use

```py
class DatabaseErrorException (Exception): 
   pass


class DbConnector:
  def __init__(self, parameters):
    self.params=parameters
    self.connection=None

  def connect():
    self.connection = psycopg2.connect(**self.parameters)
    return self.connection

  def insert_table(self, query):
    try:
      with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        rowcount = cursor.rowcount
        self.connection.commit()
      return True
    except DatabaseErrorException as ex:
      print("Error to insert table")
      return False
```

The error is the exception if try fails. For example, if table is wrong:

```py
params = {
        'db_host': 'host',
        'db_user': 'postgres_user',
        'db_pass': 'pass',
        'db_port': '5432',
        'db_database': 'test'}

dbcon_obj = DbConnector(params)
con = dbcon_obj.connect()
con.insert_table(query=insert_query)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_postgrest.py", line 51, in <module>
    count = con.insert_table(table1, query)
  insert_table
    cursor.executemany(query)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: no existe la relación «accxounts»
LINE 1: INSERT INTO accxounts (user_id, username, password, email) V...
```

But if I implement `insert_table` with Exception class:

```py
  def insert_table(self, query):
    try:
      with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(query)
        rowcount = cursor.rowcount
        self.connection.commit()
      return True
    except Exception as ex:
      print("Error to insert table")
      return False
```

I got the print in the log

```
Error to insert table
-1  rows inserted in table accxounts
```

Comment: It's not clear what your issue is. You say "exception is not raised and only print message is given", but in order for the message to be printed the exception has to have been raised. Can you show us examples of the code and output when doing it both ways so it's clearer what the two situations are?

Comment: "How can I control the exceptions using a custom class as it is done using Exception class?" I don't understand what this means. Please show a *complete* example. I should be able to copy and paste the code from your question, run it without adding anything else, and see the exact problem you are asking about. You should explain what happens when you run that code, what you want to happen instead, and how that is different.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I have updated the question, I hope it is more clear now.